# Non-Convex Polygons with "Antipodal Visibility"

Tags: reference-request, computational-geometry, plane-geometry, polygons

by "antipodal visibility" of planar, simple polygons I mean the following property:
if two points $p$ and $q$ on the polygon's boundary divide the polygon's boundary into two polylines of equal length, then the line-segment between $p$ and $q$ doesn't intersect the polygon's boundary, except in $p$ and in $q$.

Questions:

- do non-convex polygons with antipodal visibility exist?
- if yes, is anything known about their algorithmic construction (esp. of random instances)?

Comment: Take a triangle $ABC$ with $\left|AB\right| = \left|AC\right|$ and with $\measuredangle BAC$ very small (thus an isosceles triangle with an apex very high up). Let $H$ be its orthocenter. I am fairly sure $ABHC$ has antipodal visibility (and is not convex).

Comment: Any star polygon symmetrical wrt its center is antipodally visible.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I agree; your construction seems to prove existence.

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov very nice and obviously true.